# Undefined citation problem with different reason

Tags: bibtex, citing

I was using for my research paper bib style "Vancouver" and it used to compile very nicely. For the journal, yet I must have something that will include Name and Year in the text. I changed the style though for something like: \bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}. And the "undefined citation" error appeared. Please help me to find out the problem or give a hint for some other style, which will result with Name and Year (and not a reference number) in the text. Thank You in advance. The code for the beginning of the text is following:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{times,graphicx,verbatim}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
% etc.
% see the list of further useful packages
% in the Reference Guide, Sects. 2.3, 3.1-3.3

%\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{verbatim} % comment !!!!
%\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} % kodowanie windows
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{multicolumn}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{linguex}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.90}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{ex}{roundcorner=6pt,linecolor=light-gray,innermargin=1cm,outermargin=1cm,backgroundcolor=light-gray}
\mdfdefinestyle{mp}{roundcorner=4pt,linecolor=light-gray,linewidth=1.5pt}

\newcommand{\margnote}[1]{\hbadness=11111\marginpar{\begin{scriptsize}\textit{#1}\end{scriptsize}}} % margin notes -- zeby widziec notatki

%\newcommand{\margnote}[1]{\marginpar{\begin{scriptsize}\textit{}\end{scriptsize}}} % margin notes -- zeby nie bylo widac notatek






\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} % the set of all natural numbers
\newcommand{\CA}{\vdash\hspace{-0.4em}\raisebox{-0.01ex}{$\circ$}}

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program


\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Did you forgot the requested `\bibliography{yourbibfile}` ? Have you tried to build after deletion of all aux and bbl files? By the way, you should not use the `.bst` extension in the argument of `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: What really means "include Name and Year in the text" ?. Do you have to switch from Vancouver to author-year style ? Where is the style file model2-names.bst ? Where is '\biboptions` defined ?. Does `elsearticle` load a bibliography package, and which ?

Comment: Thank You! Name and Year means exactly what you are guessed. That is how i defined the bib: \bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}
I need to add something else?

Comment: You didn't answered my mots important questions... I fund the code of `model2-names.bst` and of `elsarticle.cls` on www.overleaf.com. It turns out that the later loads the `natbib` package and defines tits options by the mean of the custom macro `\biboptions`. And what is the `.bib` file, and where is it used ? Buy the way, with `natbib` you should use `\citet` or ``\citep` instead of `\cite`. Please edit your post to provide a fully compilable MWEB (minimal working example with bibliography). Without it we can not really help.